# how to assign a list of objects from grails controller to javascript array

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I am passing a list of objects from my controller to my page , on loading of my page i want to invoke a javascript function on each of the element in the list coming from the controller .. HOW can i achieve that , i know i cannot mix and match javascript and ${}(g-strings) , so i dont have any idea. pls help

code: from controller , the DurationTable contains expiry a date field in itself

```
def test = {
    [durationTablelist: DurationTable.list()]
}
```

code on gsp ::

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var myarraylist = new Array();
    myarraylist = "${durationTablelist}";
    for(counter=0;counter<"${durationTablelist.size()}";counter++){
        // call some function on each of the element in the list passed from controller
        dont know what to write here..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a bunch of ways you can do it.

1. You can use scriplets, as seen [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ddwyg3ADVCEC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=grails%20gsp%20scriptlet&source=bl&ots=_Z2ifUe7oJ&sig=eIjHtQs1qZBzKcQ9uoT8u3hud4Q&hl=en&ei=WrE2TpuYLu230AHsy93hCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&sqi=2&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=grails%20gsp%20scriptlet&f=false).
2. You could use jquery to invoke an action on your controller which returns json, and then populate the array with the json response.

I personally would do option 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like ;

```
import grails.converters.JSON

  ...
  render DurationTable.list() as JSON
```

for more info refer [here](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference)